# Why is the old Universal logo used for a 2009 movie?

Tags: production, drag-me-to-hell

*Drag Me To Hell* was released in 2009, but the Universal Picture logo which appears before the movie is quite an old one.

Why was an old logo used?

[image]

Comment: This might be considered trivia(?)

Comment: @mattiav27 How could it? The asker clearly states why the usage of an old Universal Pictures logo seems so very unusual to him.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Director can request this and the Studio has the ultimate decision as to which logo is used at the start of the picture.

Universal and others have a history of allowing changes to their logos for some movies...*Waterworld* is a good example of this.

In this case, I suspect that, Sam Raimi was probably trying make Drag Me to Hell feel like something made during the late 1970s or early 1980s when American horror films such as this were at a high point and so used the [**logo that was used from 1963 - 1990**](http://www.myfilmviews.com/2012/02/16/the-story-behind-the-universal-pictures-logo/)

In addition, Raimi said to [**ScreenCrave**](http://screencrave.com/2009-05-27/sam-raimi-interview-for-drag-me-to-hell/):

> **ScreenCrave** - What was the inspiration for old Universal logo at the start of the film?
>
> **Raimi** -  Well, the reason that logo was there was the opening scene takes place in 1969 in Pasadena. My editor, Bob Murawski thought it would be cool and appropriate if we started with a logo from that era as a way to say this is not a flashback. You’re in 1969 and here’s where that opening scene is. That was really why we started with that, plus we think that’s a really cool logo. Love that old Universal logo.

Comment: The Waterworld logo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2UQBzleE_II

Comment: @liori And that is 1:32 more of Waterworld than any person should ever see again. :D